# Error when running cifar in tensorflow

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow

I'm running tensorflow r0.11 in ubuntu 16.04.1.When running cifar10_train.py,I'm getting this error:
ValueError: Failed to find file: /tmp/cifar10_data/cifar-10-batches-bin/data_batch_1.bin
How does this happen?Can somebody help?